# Will this equation have real solutions?

Tags: functions

Consider the following equation:

$$ax^2 + bx + c = f(x)$$

$a$, $b$, and $c$ are arbitrary real constants. $f(x)$ is not a polynomial.

Does there exist a condition on $f(x)$ such that the solutions are guaranteed to be real?

---

Update:

A fixed, more detailed version of the question can be found here [Do nth degree polynomials derived using Least Squares Interpolation always have n+1 intersections with the function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166392/do-nth-degree-polynomials-derived-using-least-squares-interpolation-always-have)

Comment: lazy answer, $f(x) = ax^2 + b_1x + c_1$

Comment: Like $b^2 - 4ac \ge 0$

Comment: All functions f such that their graphs intersect the parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ in the plane $\mathbb R ^2$

Comment: This question is only slightly less vague than asking "Under what conditions will $f(x) = g(x)$?" with no constraints on either function. Which is to say, I don't think you're going to get anything very informative as an answer.

Comment: Here's a more detailed version. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166392/do-nth-degree-polynomials-derived-using-least-squares-interpolation-always-have

Answer (score 0):

Plenty. For instance: $$\begin{align}f(x) &= c \\ f(x) &= bx + k\, , \quad k \geq |c|
\\ f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c\quad\text{(solution all of $\Bbb R$)} \\ f(x) &= g(x) + ax^2 + bx + c\, ,\quad g^{-1}(\{0\})\subset \Bbb R\end{align}$$

Maybe you want a specific type of function though? The last example is probably the most general condition in this case.

Comment: please check the update.

Comment: @user120404 Ah, I see. The last example need not be a polynomial, for example $\sin x + ax^2 + bx + c$.